# Element with maximum magnitude in $A \leq \max(\sigma_{i})$, where $\sigma_{i}$ is singular values of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, svd

Let $A$ be a matrix with real values. Is it true that element with maximum magnitude in $A$ is less than $\max(\sigma_{i})$, where $\sigma_{i}$ is singular values of A? That is, is
$$ \max_{ij} |A_{ij}| \leq \sigma_{\max}(A)?$$

Comment: It is true. You can show for a $m$-by-$n$ matrix that $\max_{i,j} |A_{ij}| \leq \sigma_{\max}(A) \leq \sqrt{mn} \max_{i,j} |A_{ij}| $.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Suppose $A $ is $m\times n $. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n $ and $f_1,\ldots,f_m $ be the canonical bases of $\mathbb R^n $ and $\mathbb R^m $ respectively. Write $A=USV $ the singular value decomposition. Let $v=Ve_j $; as $V $ is a unitary,  $\|Ve_j\|=1$. Then, since $S_{pq}=0 $ if $p\ne q $,
\begin{align}
|A_{ij}|
&
=|\langle Ae_j,f_i\rangle|
=|\langle USVe_j,f_i\rangle|
=|\langle Sv,U^*f_i\rangle|\\ \ \\
&\leq\|Sv\|\,\|U^*f_i\|=\|Sv\|
=\left (\sum_{k=1}^m(Sv)_k^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\left (\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\sum_{h=1}^nS_{kh}v_h\right)^2\right)^{1/2}
=\left (\sum_{k=1}^mS_{kk}^2v_k^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq \left (\sum_{k=1}^m\sigma_\max(A)^2v_k^2\right)^{1/2}
= \sigma_\max (A)\,\|v\|=\sigma_\max (A).
\end{align}
*(note that, if $k>n $, $S_{kk} $ does not exist; but it can be taken  as zero and the inequalities still hold)*